# Maven Parent Project classes not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven projects, parent and a child project
Parent pom file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>15</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>remote</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies> ...</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>com.xx.aa,com.almworks.sqlite4java,org.apache.commons.lang3</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

child pom.xml

```
<artifactId>report</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>remote</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I instantiate parent class, I get "cannot resolve error".
I am using eclipse. I checked inside .m2 directory the jar remote2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is available inside the path. In eclipse, I get the below error in Markers,

```
Project 'report' is missing required Java project: 'remote'
```

Under Libraries, I am not able to see the jar file inside I am seeing an empty folder,

[image]

I couldn't find what is the issue. Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by converting the project ot a Faceted project and in classpath add the m2e container, the final classpath file may look like below,

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```